# Creating a Countdown Watch with a slider in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

Hello guys i need some help.

Im trying to create a countdown watch which can count down from hours, minuts and seconds. Right now im only able to create the countdown for seconds but i want the application to be able to update the seconds, minutes and hours when i "slide" with the slider. I find it very hard to update the label correctly and add "hours and minutes" to the application. Can someone please help me figuring the logic out.

This is the code i have written so far and it works fine only with seconds.. I also added a audio file which will play in the end as you can see in the code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var secondsCount = 30;
var timer = Timer()
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelmin: UILabel!


    // Slideren som slider tid for sal 1
@IBOutlet weak var sliderOutlet: UISlider!
@IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider)
{
    //Live changes the numbers
    secondsCount = Int(sender.value)
    label.text = String(secondsCount) + " Seconds"

}


    //Start button
@IBOutlet weak var startOutlet: UIButton!
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any)
{
        //Nederstående kode aktiverer funktionen counter()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    sliderOutlet.isHidden = true
    startOutlet.isHidden = true
}

    //Counter function
func counter() {
    secondsCount -= 1

    label.text = String(secondsCount) + " Seconds"

    if (secondsCount == 0)
    {
        timer.invalidate()

        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}

    //Stop button
@IBOutlet weak var stopOutlet: UIButton!
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any)
{
    timer.invalidate()
    secondsCount = 30
    sliderOutlet.setValue(30, animated: true)
    label.text = "30 Seconds"

    audioPlayer.stop()

    sliderOutlet.isHidden = false
    startOutlet.isHidden = false
}


    // viewDidLoad

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do
    {
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: ".mp3")

        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))

    }
    catch
    {
        //ERROR
    }



}
```

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum values for your slider? And what is the starting value? And, what do you want to happen when the slider value changes?

Comment: Maybe better question: In what format do you want the "countdown time" displayed? "02:34:21"? or "2 hours, 34 minutes, 21 seconds"? or something else?

Comment: I would like it to be in "2hours, 34 minutes, 21 seconds" format and the countdown watch only have to count down from 2 hours... not more.. That is because it is for a specific purpose.

Comment: What kind of resolution do you want from the slider? If moving the slider 1 pixel changes the start value by 1 second, then your slider would need to be 7200 pixels long in order to have a range of 0-2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is *one* way to convert number of seconds into a formatted hours, minutes, seconds string:

```
func hmsFromSecondsFormatted(seconds: Int) -> String {

    let h = seconds / 3600
    let m = (seconds % 3600) / 60
    let s = seconds % 60

    var newText = ""

    if h > 0 {
        newText += "\(h)"
        if h == 1 {
            newText += " hour, "
        } else {
            newText += " hours, "
        }
    }

    if m > 0 || h > 0 {
        newText += "\(m)"
        if m == 1 {
            newText += " minute, "
        } else {
            newText += " minutes, "
        }
    }

    newText += "\(s)"
    if s == 1 {
        newText += " second"
    } else {
        newText += " seconds"
    }

    return newText

}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
label.text = hmsFromSecondsFormatted(secondsCount)
```

The multiple `if` conditions give you two things:

1. a result of singular / plural time component names (so you get "1 second" instead of "1 seconds"), and
2. returns only the necessary time components. So, 45 seconds is returned as "45 seconds" instead of "0 hours, 0 minutes, 45 seconds"

In your actual app, you probably will also use localized strings for the time component names.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of logic i needed thank you very much for your input!